# logkeys not working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, log

After installing logkeys from synaptic, it does not work, hangs when trying to start, even the output file is not created. Compiling solves this particular problem, but the now the output file is blank. How can i know what may be he problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, so I installed with `apt-get` and it worked like a charm. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then type:

```
sudo apt-get install logkeys
```

Link to `pt_br/uk_table` or another language table: [Keymaps](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Keymaps)

```
sudo logkeys -s -m /home/user/pt_BR.map -o /home/user/logkeys.log
```

Answer (score 1):

What command are you using to run it? When I tried to do

```
sudo logkeys --start
```

The program stalled for me too. I realized I needed to specify a keymap. If you have a US keyboard, you can type

```
sudo logkeys --start --us-keymap
```

For other keyboards type

```
sudo logkeys --start --keymap=/path/to/my/keymap.map
```

The fact that logkeys doesn't tell you a keymap isn't specified looks like a bug to me.

Comment: There are issues with logkeys and newer versions of Ubuntu, so I've written my own keylogger that you can find here: https://github.com/gsingh93/simple-key-logger

Answer (score 1):

It can be done simple steps. First open a terminal and do the following

1. Step1:
   Installing logkeys using sudo `apt-get install logkeys`
2. Step2:
   Start it by `sudo logkeys --start`
3. Step3:
   Type anything you need, you can use cntrl, shift, etc.
   Logfile is stored on the location /var/log/ unless you specified -o option
4. Step4:
   To view it, type `sudo gedit /var/log/logkeys.log` 
   (Assume gedit installed on your system).
   Instead you can use `sudo nano /var/log/logkeys.log`

Answer (score 0):

The apt-get package is broken, looks like since 12.10

It installs fine, but does not output anything to the files.

```
strace logkeys -s
```

Clearly shows the errors.

The details and confirmations of this are here
https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/issues/detail?id=108

---

You'll have to install yourself from sources.

See
https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Documentation

---

I have messaged the package maintainer.